# js - passing & reurning multiple value

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I can't return multiple values in javascript return statement.  Would it be useful to wrap these values in a js object?  or other solution?

```
function buildSomething()


    var t = [];
    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    var h = [];

    var myValues = fnGetData(t,y,x,h);



function fnGetData(t,y,x,h) 
{

 //  do something 
 // return t,y,x,h

}
```

Comment: Returning an array of values? `return [ t, y, x, h ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking closely at your code, it looks like you're trying to pass multiple values **into** a function.  Using an object for this is a common idiom in JavaScript.

```
var values = {
    t: t,
    x: x,
    y: y,
    h: h
};
```

It also makes it easy to handle default data

```
function fnGetData(data)  {
   data.t = data.t || [];
   data.x = data.x || ["default", "values"];
}
```

I'm not sure if you're using jQuery or not, but there's a common jQuery idiom for this as well:

```
function fnGetData(data)  {
   $.extend(data, {
      t: [],
      x: ["intial", "values"]
   });
}
```

Comment: then reference them as myValues.t[n]?

Answer (score 1):

Using an object is probably your best bet:

```
function getData(t, y, x, h) {
    // ...
    return {
        t: t,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        h: h
    };
}
```

Then you can access any value in the returned object by name.

Answer (score 0):

The choices you have are to return them as an array or an object, where an object is the more logical choice since you can give the properties clear names that result in better code.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to return an object from a function as others have suggested. I'd probably go that route. An object is also easier to deal with and less likely to pollute the global scope.

Another option, if you need to call a function like in your example, is to return an array. Returning an array can come in handy if you need to call a function with your returned values using `Function.apply`. `Function.apply` takes an array and converts it into function parameters.

For example:

```
someFunc.apply(this, [t,x,y,h]);
```